# Titanium how to use images in switch

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am new to titanium and am working on switches and I have two images **ON** and **OFF** and I when we swipe the **ON** it should switch to the **OFF**..
Here are the two images I am trying to use..

[image: OFF] [image: ON]

I dont know how to use these images..The only thing I can do is a default switch

**Here is the coding**

```
var basicSwitch = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
value:true ,// mandatory property for iOS 
color: 'white',
left : 40,
top:0,
backgroundColor:'black'
});
cview.add(basicSwitch);

basicSwitch.addEventListener('change',function(e){
Ti.API.info('Switch value: ' + basicSwitch.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

The natively built in Slider does not support custom images (except on iOS). I would recommend you to implement this as a button which changes if it is swiped in the desired direction.

```
var switchButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    image: "/disabledSwitch.png", //exchange for your location
    //Add the dimensions
    title: "OFF" });

switchButton.addEventListener ('swipe', function() {
    if (e.direction == "right" && e.source.title == "OFF" {
        //Enable the "switch"
        switchButton.setImage("Your active image");
        switchButton.setTitle("ON");
        //Set your desired actions
    } else if (.direction == "left" && e.source.title == "ON" {
        //Disable the "switch"
        switchButton.setImage("Your inactive image");
        switchButton.setTitle("OFF");
        //Set your desired actions
    } });

cview.add(switchButton);
```

You could also additionally add a click listener.

Comment: Thanks @Robin, adding "background:'transparent'" would complete switch control.